# Why picker trigger twice onselectedindexchangedevent in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, picker, selecteditem, selectedindexchanged

Why picker twice time triggered first time i get the values of Selecteditem second time it seems to be null all. How to resolve this issue.

```
private void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double vatPercent;
            object selectedPicker = ((Picker)sender).BindingContext;

            Picker picker = ((Picker)sender);
            object vatItem = picker.SelectedItem;

            int index = picker.SelectedIndex;
            if (vatItem != null)
            {
                VatRate vatRate = vatItem as VatRate;
                vatPercent = vatRate.Rate;
            }
            else
                vatPercent = 0;
}
```

Comment: Something in code elsewhere must be causing Picker's SelectedIndex or SelectedItem to change to null. If you have a Binding on either of those, it could also be caused by code that changes the bound value - maybe to an invalid value, so the result is null? This is all that can be said, without seeing all related code: XAML or cs that declares picker. Any code that might change SelectedItem or SelectedIndex. Any code that might touch the bound value, if there is a Binding.

Comment: Also, try to reduce the problem to the simplest case. If you have any "Binding" in the Picker declaration, temporarily change to use a hardcoded value instead, if possible. If not possible, then Bind to something that no other code is touching. Similarly, if there is any code that references the picker, comment out that code. Or duplicate the picker, give the duplicate a different `x:Name` attribute - so no code knows about it. My point is to eliminate any outside interference - see if you can get a situation that doesn't send the null value. Then start adding to that simple case.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2075
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7646

You could try the suggestions below:

1. Update Xamarin Forms to latest version.
2. Use the `ObservableCollection` as ItemSource.